# How to move menus and sub menus

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone please show me how to move a menu and its sub-menus from one Menu Location to another in one shot.

I have about 15 Sub menus for each main menu and I would like to move the main menu and accompanying menus to another menu location.

Can someone show me how its done.

Thank you

Carlton

Comment: You can use "Batch" button if you need to move menulinks. If you are talking about location as module position, then it's done under Extensions > Module manager.

Comment: It might help to clarify if you are asking about moving menu items from one menu to another or if you are asking about moving menus to an alternative module position.

Answer (score 3):

To move a menu location to another, you mean to assign it to a new position? If yes, then following steps needs to be followed:

1) In templates/tpl_name/templateDetails.xml : add a new position as follows:

```
 <position>position_name</position>
```

2) In templates/tpl_name/index.php : add the following line wherever you want the menu location to be:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position_name" />
```

3) Login to administrator section now, create a new module from Module Manager of type `menu` and assign it to the position `position_name`

4) Now your menu will be assigned it to new location.

5) Note: If you already have a position then you can skip step (1)& (2)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your template has to support a module position in the target area.

Then you can go to the modules page in the backend, open the menu module and on the right site "position" you can select or write the position name.

If you are confirm with HTML you can take a look into the index.php in the template folder. Here you should see how position are implemented (short php codes). Just copy a position and rename it. Then you can write that name in the model position field in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

To move menu from one position to other, you need to either create a new module or change module positions.

There are several module positions assigned in a template, to check which position is exactly meeting your needs, just check all the positions.

This can be done very easily. Here are the following steps :

1. Just Log in to the Admin panel and go to the **Template manager**.
2. Click on the **Options** button placed at the right side, and then make ' **Preview Module Positions'** to **ENABLED**.

You can check it with the screenshot attached.

[image]

[image: Position to be managed]

3. And last you just need to go to your website URL, and add **?tp=1** to the URL. For example :

> example.com?tp=1

And if you need to create new positions you can do it by doing changes in your template's index and xml file. And that is already mentioned in @ruchika answer.